# How do I create a template page with a specific widget as the content?

Tags: widgets, templates

I have installed a widget so that I may add testimonials. This widget cycles through the testimonials in the sidebar and everything is fine. What I now want to do is create a testimonials page that retrieves all the entries from this widget. The functionality already exists in the widget to retrieve all the testimonials, however I cannot find a way to get the widget explicitly.

I have tried [the_widget()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) but cannot work out what the widget's PHP class name is.

Is there another way of grabbing this widget?

[edit]
@user8982, thank-you for your suggestions, however this is not what I require.

- I am using Wordpress V3.2.
- 1,    The plugin I am tring to access is 'Testimonials Widget' by
  'j0hnsmith'.
- I am using a custom theme.

I have already created a template file.

I have a testimonials widget registered in the main sidebar. I would like to, in my template, retrieve this widget (as an object preferably) and have it echo every testimonial instead of showing/hiding them one at a time.

Comment: Does it create a new database table? You may need to run a custom sql query to get the testimonials on your template.

Comment: Yes, it does. I was hoping there was a way to do it without resorting to creating my own sql...

Comment: @Rutwick Gangurde: Can you create an answer please.

Comment: Build a custom sql query that selects the latest testimonials from the table that the plugin creates. Use $wpdb->get_results($sql_query) to get the results as an array, and then loop over it in your markup.
What testimonial plugin are you using?

Comment: @rutwick What I meant was, create an answer post so I can mark it as the answer. I have duplicated the sql in the widget into the template and it works.

Comment: Created the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a custom sql query that selects the latest testimonials from the table that the plugin creates. Use $wpdb->get_results($sql_query) to get the results as an array, and then loop over it in your markup.

Answer (score 1):

First of all when ever you ask any question you should mention in which environment you are working. like-

1. Wordpress Ver
2. Plugin Name
3. Your theme name
4. Any other specification etc

Regarding your question i think below links are useful please have a look

1. http://webdesign.anmari.com/1649/shortcode-any-widget/
2. http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets

To create custom template you have to create a php file for example

For more details see below link. use http://

codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates